# How to select specified element with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs, selectors-api

I want to select first `<span>` and second `<span>` , then get their innerText.
[image]

Bur i try to use `xpath` or `document.querySelector` , they are no working.  I `console.log` my array show null.

```
// I want to select first <span>
function getDate() {
    var date = document.querySelector('div.movie_intro_info_r li').selectedIndex = 1;
    return Array.prototype.map.call(date, function (e) {
        return e.innerHTML;
    });
};
// I want to select second <span>
function getMovieLength() {
    var movieLength = document.querySelectorAll(x('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/span[2]'));
    return Array.prototype.map.call(movieLength, function (e) {
        return e.innerText;
    });
};

casper.then(function () {
    casper.each(movieHref, function (casper, url) {
        casper.thenOpen(url, function () {
            casper.waitForSelector('div.btn_gray_info.gabtn', function () {
                console.log('wait for element');
            });
            releaseDate[urlCount] = this.evaluate(getDate);
            console.log(releaseDate[urlCount]);// show null

            movieLength[urlCount] = this.evaluate(getMovieLength);
            console.log(movieLength[urlCount]);// show null
            urlCount++;
        });
    });
});
```

How can I just select specified element and get its innerText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a bit too complex for what you are trying to do. You should consider using the `fetchText` method with CSS selectors:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('YOUR_URL', function () {
  this.echo(this.fetchText('.movie_intro_info_r > span:first-of-type'));
  this.echo(this.fetchText('.movie_intro_info_r > span:nth-of-type(2)'));
}).run();
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply truly , i try your code google fetchText see the API and others code from stackoverflow.   I still can't print anything , i update the code i try on my question . Can you check my code and give me suggestion what step should i miis it ?  Thank you very much !

Comment: I try to check it exists or not like '    if (this.exists('.movie_intro_info_r > span:nth-of-type(2)')) {
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }'
print no.

Comment: It's no problem now , the reason is i put the code in wrong place from your suggestion .   Thanks for your help , blessing.